# what is the meaning of the pin out with 3.3V2, 3.3V3, 3.3V4 etc. I understand its 3.3 volts DC

Tags: pcb

What is the meaning on a circuit board pin out when you see 3.3V2 or 3.3V3 or 3.3v4 etc.

Answer (score 2):

It likely means that there are three 3.3 volt supply rails called: -

- <kbd>**3.3V2**</kbd>
- <kbd>**3.3V3**</kbd>

and

- <kbd>**3.3V4**</kbd>

There may be a <kbd>**3.3V1**</kbd> and a <kbd>**3.3V0**</kbd> as well.

They may all be connected via 0 ohm resistors or possibly inductors or, maybe they are generated separately using several 3.3 volt voltage regulators. It's not uncommon to see this.